# Why do Personal Campaign Pages stay live after their Contribution Page is closed

Tags: civicontribute, pcp, personal-campaign-pages

I'm working with someone who posed the following question to me:

> Why do personal campaign pages stay live, even following the closing date for the contribution page they are attached to?  How do I make it so they automatically turn off when the contribution page does?"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joe says it's a bug; I say it's a feature! If you have donors fundraising for you, you might not want to have their writeup and list of donors disappear when the campaign is over. Something elegant ought to be done to have the PCP still visible, the contribution page disabled, and not have it seem like the link is broken, however.

Comment: While it might be desirable to expose that information, keeping the pages live after the main one is disabled doesn't make sense to me. If desired one can expose views of the donors and write-ups after the campaign has ended.

Comment: Upon further investigation, it seems the PCP page still loads but without the "Contribute" button, which seems fairly reasonable. I may see if I can make a patch that swaps the Contribute button for a short sentence indicating donations are no longer accepted on this form (as the PCP language likely still invites contributions) rather than just hiding it.

Answer (score 0):

If true, it seems like a bug. Try replicating on demo site and then file an issue.